# creating Realm database from user oriented (cough) source

Tags: spreadsheet

Are there any packages for easily creating a Realm database from something that a user would be able to edit? To be more specific, I'm thinking of a spreadsheet, which the user could export as a CSV, which could then be quickly processed into Realm, like with a JSON file.

Comment: That is a great question and it is high on the todo list for the Realm Browser (included in the distribution). We are planning several ways to make it easier to migrate existing data, including importing CSV and other formats, as well as creating data right in the Browser.

Having said that, one option right now could be Matthew Cheok's [Realm+JSON](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON).